# Clean url in IIS 5.0

Tags: php, iis, iis-5

Hai

Thanks for everything. I have successfully implemented clean URL in local. Very nice site.

Now my objective is to create a clean URL web site in PHP Microsoft IIS 5.0, I know this in Apache. But I don't know how this on IIS. Does any one give me a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are commercial/free components that allow you to achieve URL rewriting on IIS 5.0. Few worth mentioning tools are:

- [ISAPI REwrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/) (commercial, free version with limited functionality is available)
- [Ionic's Isapi Rewrite Filter aka IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com/) (donationware, better than most other free ones)

[IIS URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) is another option but requires IIS7; to run IIS7 you need Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

See:

**[IIS  URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite)**